Sitecore 10.2 AKS deployed code Integration with Azure B2C using Owin Middleware to generate id token
We have Sitecore 10.2 with .NET framework 4.8 integrated with B2C using OwinMiddleware.
Below are the library details.
Microsoft.Owin V: 4.1.1.0
Microsoft.Owin.Security 4.1.0.0
Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth 4.1.0.0
We are not seeing OnSecurityB2CTokenValidated Method is getting called every time only in AKS deployed code and its being called in docker based code without any issues. Due to this we are having inconsistent issue in our site.
We are storing the token generated in OnSecurityB2CTokenValidated method.
When the token is not generated, system would recall the login as td_token is not successfully generated. We found this is a major problem when we suppose to go live in PROD setup as the token was generated after 10th time call of login. As a result, site reloads the login page multiple times.

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(abcd.Foundation.Authentication.Startup))]
namespace abcd.Foundation.Authentication
{
    public class Startup
    {
        
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            
            var initializeOwinMiddlewareArgs = new abcde.Foundation.AzureADInternalUser.Pipelines.InitializeOwinMiddlewareArgs(app);
            CorePipeline.Run("initializeowinmiddlewareAzureAD", initializeOwinMiddlewareArgs);
            CorePipeline.Run("initializeowinmiddlewareabcd", new Pipelines.InitializeOwinMiddlewareArgs(app));
            
        }
    }


}
#################################
public class OwinMiddleWareAdviser
{
public void Process(InitializeOwinMiddlewareArgs args)
{
    ConfigureAuth(args.App);
}
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app) { ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType); app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()); app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication( new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions { AuthenticationType = AuthenicationConfigs.B2C_AuthenticationType, AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive, Authority = AuthenicationConfigs.B2C_Authority + AuthenicationConfigs.B2C_SignUpSignInPolicyId + AuthenicationConfigs.B2C_PolicyVersion, ClientId = AuthenicationConfigs.B2C_ClientId, RedirectUri= AuthenicationConfigs.B2C_RedirectUri+ AuthenicationConfigs.B2C_GetRoleDetails, PostLogoutRedirectUri = AuthenicationConfigs.B2C_LogoutRedirectUri, ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken, Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications {

    RedirectToIdentityProvider = OnRedirectToIdentityProvider,
    AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,
    SecurityTokenValidated = OnSecurityB2CTokenValidated,

},
TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
{
    NameClaimType = AuthenicationConfigs.B2C_NameClaimType,
    ValidateIssuer = false,
},
Scope = AuthenicationConfigs.B2C_scope + " " + AuthenicationConfigs.B2C_ClientId,
CookieManager = new SystemWebCookieManager(),

public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app) { ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType); app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()); app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication( new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions { AuthenticationType = AuthenicationConfigs.B2C_AuthenticationType, AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive, Authority = AuthenicationConfigs.B2C_Authority + AuthenicationConfigs.B2C_SignUpSignInPolicyId + AuthenicationConfigs.B2C_PolicyVersion, ClientId = AuthenicationConfigs.B2C_ClientId, RedirectUri= AuthenicationConfigs.B2C_RedirectUri+ AuthenicationConfigs.B2C_GetRoleDetails, PostLogoutRedirectUri = AuthenicationConfigs.B2C_LogoutRedirectUri, ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken, Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications {

    RedirectToIdentityProvider = OnRedirectToIdentityProvider,
    AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,
    SecurityTokenValidated = OnSecurityB2CTokenValidated,

},
TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
{
    NameClaimType = AuthenicationConfigs.B2C_NameClaimType,
    ValidateIssuer = false,
},
Scope = AuthenicationConfigs.B2C_scope + " " + AuthenicationConfigs.B2C_ClientId,
CookieManager = new SystemWebCookieManager(),
}); 

} 

private Task OnRedirectToIdentityProvider(RedirectToIdentityProviderNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification) 
{ var policy = notification.OwinContext.Get("Policy");

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(policy) && !policy.Equals(AuthenicationConfigs.B2C_SignUpSignInPolicyId))
{
    notification.ProtocolMessage.Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenId;
    notification.ProtocolMessage.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken;
    notification.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress = notification.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress.ToLower().Replace(AuthenicationConfigs.B2C_SignUpSignInPolicyId.ToLower(), policy.ToLower());
}
return Task.FromResult(0);
}
private Task OnAuthenticationFailed(AuthenticationFailedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification)
{
    var errorMessage = notification.Exception.Message;
    Log.Info("ConfigureAuth Owinmiddleware AuthenticationFailed" + errorMessage, this);
    if (!errorMessage.Contains("IDX21329"))
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(AuthenicationConfigs.login_RedirectWhenErrorUri, true);
        notification.HandleResponse();
    }

    return Task.FromResult(0);
}
private Task OnSecurityB2CTokenValidated(
               SecurityTokenValidatedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification)
{           
    var idToken = notification.ProtocolMessage?.IdToken;

    HttpContext.Current.Session[Constants.userB2CTokenId] = idToken;

    return Task.FromResult(0);
}
##################################################################
Controller code:

public void Login() { try {

    if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        _authenticationService.ExpireAllCookies(this);

        var redirectUrl = Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri.ToString();
        if (!redirectUrl.Contains("sso."))
            this.ControllerContext.Controller.ViewBag.CurrentUrl = redirectUrl;
        
        var authenticationProperties = new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = redirectUrl };

        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(authenticationProperties,
            new string[] { AuthenicationConfigs.B2C_AuthenticationType, AuthenicationConfigs.B2C_SignUpSignInPolicyId });
    }
    else
        Response.Redirect(AuthenicationConfigs.B2C_RedirectUri);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Logger.Error("Error while excecuting Login()"+ ex.Message, this);

}
} 

#########################################
//This method is a Redirect URL end point configured in B2C app. Called a Get method inside just to delay or activate the service so that it would wait for the token response. 

public async Task GetRoleDetails()
{
    var id_token = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var response = await client.GetAsync(AuthenicationConfigs.B2C_RedirectUri+"/service/GetRoleDetails");

        if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Found) // 302 Found
        {
            var location = response.Headers.Location;
            if (location != null)
            {
                var query = location.Query;
                var queryDictionary = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(query);
                string idToken = queryDictionary["id_token"];
                
            }
        }

        if (HttpContext.Session[Constants.userB2CTokenId] != null)
            id_token = HttpContext.Session[Constants.userB2CTokenId].ToString();
    
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(id_token))
        {
            if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.ControllerContext.Controller.ViewBag.CurrentUrl))
                ViewBag.CurrentUrl = AuthenicationConfigs.B2C_RedirectUri;
            _authenticationService.Relogin(this);
        }   
        else
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.ControllerContext.Controller.ViewBag.CurrentUrl))
                Response.Redirect("/");
            else
                Response.Redirect(this.ControllerContext.Controller.ViewBag.CurrentUrl);
        }               

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        
    }
}

Code under : authenticationService.Relogin


public void Relogin(Controller controller)
{
    ExpireAllCookies(controller);

    var redirectUrl = AuthenicationConfigs.B2C_RedirectUri;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(controller.ControllerContext?.Controller?.ViewBag?.CurrentUrl))
        redirectUrl = controller.ControllerContext.Controller.ViewBag.CurrentUrl;
    var authenticationProperties = new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = redirectUrl, IsPersistent = true };
    controller.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(authenticationProperties,
        new string[] { AuthenicationConfigs.B2C_AuthenticationType, AuthenicationConfigs.B2C_SignUpSignInPolicyId });
}
public void ExpireAllCookies(Controller controller)
{
    if (controller.HttpContext != null)
    {
        int cookieCount = controller.HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Count;
        for (var i = 0; i < cookieCount; i++)
        {
            var cookie = controller.HttpContext.Request.Cookies[i];
            if (cookie != null)
            {
                if (cookie.Name == ".AspNet.Cookies")
                {
                    var expiredCookie = new HttpCookie(cookie.Name)
                    {
                        Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1),
                        Domain = cookie.Domain
                    };
                    controller.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(expiredCookie); 
                }
            }
        }

        controller.HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Clear();
    }
}

